# Using Email to trigger SharePoint workflow

Tags: workflow, email

We are currently designing a system to handle help desk functionality.

One of the things we want to do, is to allow a user to send an email, that will trigger the creation and start of a workflow.

Is this possible using standard functionality in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure about SharePoint 2010 but one thing that you can do with SharePoint 2007 is to Enable a List to Receive Emails and once the Email is added to the List / Lib you can configure the Workflow on Item Added.

PS:This answer will help someone who want to do it in the SharePoint 2007.

Comment: haven't tested it but sounds like a good solution

Comment: Thanks, with your answer I knew what to search for, there is a function call EMailRouting in 2010 that does this. http://furuknap.blogspot.com/2009/10/sharepoint-2010-features-list.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happens because the email is submitted by a system account. WF don't fire in that case. I'll have to do some research to figure out how to fix that.

Edit: See here- http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2009/03/14/workflows-do-not-start.aspx